# Spring DispatcherServlet with Image Servlet Configuration

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I am trying to setup my application to use Spring and also an image serving servlet.  I have looked through the other posts and found similiar topics but can't seem to get my configuration to work correctly.  I am using Spring 3.0 and using tomcat 7 as my app server.  here is my config:

```
<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>viewer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.billy.viewer.servlet.ImageServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/imageServlet/imgServlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>       
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>viewer</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/web/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>imageServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/images/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>list.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
<beans:import resource="controllers.xml" />

<beans:bean id="imageService" class="com.billy.viewer.service.ImageService"></beans:bean>
```

displayImage.jsp contains this in the body

```
<img alt="Test" src="/images/${image.imageId}">
```

ImageServlet

```
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final int DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 10240;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    int imageId = Integer.valueOf(request.getPathInfo().substring(1));

    System.out.println("Image id: "+imageId);
}
```

}

I get to my page fine and I can see the other output above the img tag but the image never shows up.  I am not seeing my system.out.println of Image id from the servelt either.  I have no error message in my console.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All seems fine. Check with firebug what is the actual response for the image request (or try opening it with your browser).

I find it strange that you have `imgServlet-context.xml`.

By the way, there is no need for a servlet to do this. You can safely map your dispatcher servlet to `/*`, and use a spring controller to handle `@RequestMapping("/images/{id}")`.

When you specify urls you'd better use `src="<c:url value="/images/${..}" />"` - this will resolve the URL relative to the current context. The other option is to use relative path - i.e. `src="images/${..}"`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I removed the imageServlet-context.xml.  I had that in there when I was trying something else.  I guess I misunderstood some other posts.  I thought that if the image is outside the application on the local file system somewhere that I need to stream it through a servlet and that I can't get the page data and the image in the same request?  If I could then this example is much easier.  I already have the image in byte[] format in the model.

Comment: @blong824 yes, you are right - you have to stream it. As I said - check with firebug.

Comment: I checked firebug and I do not see any errors there either.  The src of the images is src="/image/2".

Comment: Looking at it some more I see that the image src is: http://localhost:9090/images/2
 which should get into my imageServlet's doGet method correct?  The only thing the doGet does is the System.out.println statment but that does not get displayed in the console.  I am going to try to implement the method and return and image but I thought this first test would show the message.

Comment: Sorry for all the comments in a row.  I was able to get into the doGet method of my servlet by putting this url in a browser, http://localhost:9090/viewer/images/2.  So there is a disconnect between my jsp img src tag and how I define my mapping.  Should I have to add viewer (which is the name of my app) to the img src tag?  Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the c:url tag from standard tag library for img and other URLs which should be your web app context relative. URL you specified with "/images/${image.imageId}" because of leading "/" points to root context or /images context instead of your web app context and it will work only if you deploy your web app as root context. With c:url it will always work, when app is root and when it's non-root context.